# Changing text file using HashMap

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following:

> read the text from a file
>   remove everything(numbers, special characters...) except letters
>   store the new text(without the numbers and special characters) in a hash map and then save in a new text file

My problem is when I am saving the values from the hash map to the file. I can't handle the new lines, for example in the original text there is a new line after the fifth word but I can't do that in the new file. Here is the code:

```
 while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = input.nextLine();
         String newStr = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+"," ");

         for (String retval: newStr.split(" ", 0)){         
             myMap.put(counter,retval);
             counter = counter +1;
          }
         myMap.put(myMap.size()+1, "\n");
     }
     for(int i = 0; i<myMap.size(); i++){ 
         out.print(myMap.get(i) + " ");      
     }
```

Comment: Can you please post a example of a file, expected output and real output?

Comment: `out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"))` will give you a newline character.

Comment: @berry120 you should not be using platform specific new lines nowadays. File generated on Windows might be opened on Linux 50ms later. It no longer helps and will actually make your programs less portable. Use `"\n"` unless you have really good reason not to.

Comment: Input: Computer programming, History of programming
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia (081110)

Comment: Expected output: Computer programming  History of programming
From Wikipedia the free encyclopedia

Comment: the thing is that i must store all the words in a hashmap and then create a new file with it it must look like the original (with the same new lines)

Comment: WOW thank you so much it worked with line.seperator()

Comment: @berry120 thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The code looks more complicated than the problem.

More simpler would be to read a line, process the line and write the line. Something like this:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {

    String line = input.nextLine();
    String newStr = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+"," ");
    out.print(newStr + System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
}
```